# How to Auto create db table in cloud sql when deploy spring boot application to gcp app engine

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I want to create db table in mysql when deploy spring boot application to gcp.
Using below code:

1. Create a schema.sql file in resource folder

   ```
    select 1 from dual;
   ```
2. Create a student.sql file in resource folder
   which have all query for create table and insert command.

   ```
    USE student;

    create table student (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    ENUMBER VARCHAR(50),
    FIRSTSUBMITDATE datetime,
    LASTSUBMITDATE datetime,
    TIMEZONE VARCHAR(50),
    SWCREATEDBY VARCHAR(50),
    SWMODIFYBY VARCHAR(50)
    );
   ```
3. application.property:

   ```
    spring.datasource.platform=mysql
    spring.datasource.data=classpath:student.sql
    spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
   ```

Not getting any error and not create my tables.

Comment: Is your DB connection is OK? Did you test it on App Engine? Then can you show how do you set up the connection to the database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create db table in Cloud MySQL by cloud build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975434/how-to-create-db-table-in-cloud-mysql-by-cloud-build)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in properties

> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action= drop and create
> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas=true
> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata